# Sping Boot DefaultSecurityFilterChain configuration is different in test than in production

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test

We'd like to secure the HTTP endpoint `metrics` that is a built-in endpoint of Spring Boot. Therefore, we write own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, see below

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(95)
    public class MetricsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value("${metrics.username}")
        private String metricsUsername;

        @Value("${metrics.password}")
        private String metricsPassword;

        @Autowired
        private MyAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
              .withUser(metricsUsername).password("{noop}" + metricsPassword)
              .roles("METRICS");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable(); // disable csrf for our requests.
            http
                .antMatcher("/metrics") //
                .httpBasic()    //
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint) //
                .and()  //
                .authorizeRequests()    //
                .antMatchers("/metrics").authenticated();   //
        }

    }
```

My Spring Boot test for testing the authentication is

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MetricsEndpointTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetMetricsForbidden() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/metrics"))
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMetrics() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/metrics")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + getBasicAuthentication("testmetricsuser", "testmetricspass")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    private static String getBasicAuthentication(String user, String password) {
        String token = user + ":" + password;
        try {
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(token.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot encode with UTF-8", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The test `testGetMetricsForbidden` fails.
When I debugged the class `WebSecurity` during the test run and in production, I can find following difference in the variable `securityFilterChains` :

In production:
[image]
In test:
[image]

The difference is that in production we have five security filter chains and in test six security filter chains. The sixth filter chain is responsible that the test fails because it matches at first. I think the `@Order` is the reason for the order in the test. My question is how can I disabled that sixth filter in my test.

Comment: We use Spring Boot version 2.0.9.RELEASE

Comment: Your test worked for me (except that I used the default path `/actuator/metrics`). I suspect you have some code you haven't shown, like maybe an additional `WebSecurityAdapter` that is on the test classpath but not the app classpath?

Comment: I'll second what Dave has said. Can you try and find all instances of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? Since there is one in your test that doesn't happen in production I'd especially pay attention to test files which might have an embedded test configuration that adds an additional WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints. My team decide to update first to the newest Spring Boot version and look if that helps. If not, I will prepare a small example.